# javafx "setstyle" time by time will lost style which was set before

Tags: java, css, javafx

code:
I add a button in stage:

```
Button btn = new Button("Change size");
```

then set the current text color:

```
btn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red");
```

set button action for change the text size:

```
btn.setOnAction(e->btn.setStyle("-fx-font-size:19"));
```

I set color style first for a button.and it works, the text color is red.
when I click the button the size also changed but the color back to default.

What I want is: when I set size, the button can keep the current style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use inline styles. Use an external style sheet:

```css
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

and attach it to the scene with `scene.getStylesheets().add(...);` (passing in the resource name for the external style sheet).

Then in your code you can use the inline style to change the style dynamically:

```
Button btn = new Button("Change size");
btn.setOnAction(e->btn.setStyle("-fx-font-size:19"));
```

If you want (and it's probably better), you can also use the external style sheet for the "dynamic" style, e.g. by using a [`PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html):

```css
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}

.button:sized {
    -fx-font-size: 19pt ; 
}
```

and

```
btn.setOnAction(e -> 
    btn.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("sized"), true));
```

Comment: Thanks, James. If I wanna do it like this:   Button btn = new Button("Change size");
        ColorPicker colorpicker = new ColorPicker();
        ComboBox sizebox = new ComboBox();
        sizebox.getItems().addAll("13", "15", "18", "19");
        colorpicker.setOnAction(e-> btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#"+Integer.toHexString(colorpicker.getValue().hashCode())));
        sizebox.setOnAction(e-> btn.setStyle("-fx-font-size:"+sizebox.getValue().toString()));
I wanna change color style by ColorPicker and font size style by size ComboBox.        So it can't set by CSS.

Comment: @A.Sheh You could use the same technique (at least, for a fixed set of values); you would just have more style classes/pseudoclasses. For colors, you can use external CSS if you define a looked-up color and then dynamically change the value of the looked-up color via a call to `setStyle`. It's not documented, but exactly the same trick will work with font sizes too. If that is your real question, you should make it your question, instead of the one you asked.

Comment: Thanks, James, I add a new question in below link. I just want to come true the same function as scene builder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379559/javafx-change-style-of-a-node-frequently-not-by-css

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
btn.setOnAction(e->btn.setStyle("-fx-font-size:19;-fx-text-fill:red"));
```

but

I agree with James https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347126/6280796

> Don't use inline styles. Use an external style sheet.