# javafx change style of a node frequently not by CSS

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Example is 3 nodes in stage: button, colorpicker and comboBox(for change text size) .

```
Button btn = new Button("Change color and size");
ColorPicker colorpicker = new ColorPicker();
ComboBox sizebox = new ComboBox();
sizebox.getItems().addAll("13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "22");
```

ColorPicker will change the button background color by customer, and sizebox will change the text size by customer.

```
colorpicker.setOnAction(e-> btn.setStyle("-fx-background-  color:#"+Integer.toHexString(colorpicker.getValue().hashCode())));
sizebox.setOnAction(e-> btn.setStyle("-fx-font-size:"+sizebox.getValue().toString()));`
```

Current result is when I set color by colorpicker then to set size, the current color which just set by colorpicker will be remove to default after change size. How can I come true this function?

Like Scene Build, you can change the "text fill" many times but not impact size, or change size but not impact "text fill".

[image: Scene Builder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a binding that depends on the values of both controls and recompute the style from both of them even if only one changes:

```
Button btn = new Button("Change color and size");
ColorPicker colorpicker = new ColorPicker();
ComboBox sizebox = new ComboBox();
sizebox.getItems().addAll("13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "22");

btn.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    Color color = colorpicker.getValue();
    Object size = sizebox.getValue();

    String style = color == null ? "" : "-fx-background-color:#" + Integer.toHexString(color.hashCode());
    return size == null ? style : style + ";-fx-font-size:" + size;
}, colorpicker.valueProperty(), sizebox.valueProperty()));
```